# SSH Bash Jail Session

Tags: ssh, security, account-restrictions

I've seen some game tunneling service providers that jails the customer's account to a Information screen upon login and any input is ignored. Ctrl+C closes the SSH session, and disconnecting. This basically jails the user, but maintains the Tunnel.

This made me very curious how it's done. Does anyone knows how this could be done?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can achieve this by setting the user's login shell to something very restricted, e.g. something like "[Sleep Dummy Shell](http://www.mariovaldez.net/software/sleepshell/)". Quoting it's website,

> This is a simple do-nothing, sleep-forever program that can be used as a login shell (in Linux or Unix) to keep the connection open but without interactive shell. We use it to create SSH accounts for users who will only use them for SSH-tunneling; to create an encrypted tunnel to our servers [...]
>
> Most restricted shells still allow execution of local commands from the SSH account. Setting the account shell to something like `/bin/false` (or any other simple programs) usually won't work because the tunnel is closed as soon as the program finish its execution. Sleep Dummy Shell just sleeps until its execution is terminated by the user or the tunnel is closed.

You get the idea, a simple program does a part the trick, `sleepshell.c` has ~20 lines of C.

*I'm not sure if this already is secure enough*, i.e. what this means for using `ssh <server> /bin/bash` or similar, for example.

[See this answer (by michael-n) for more hints and information.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29772/11539)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually interested with a Bash version of it. I happened to came out with Sleep Dummy too before creating this thread.

Answer (score 0):

There are quick and easy ways to do it with bash as the shell, but they aren't very secure.  (there have been several security flaws found in the last few years with the authorized_keys 'command" directive, and with Bash's environment variables.  Should be safe now, unless there is another lurking bug...)

If you want to do this safely, but still want to write a script in bash to display the output, I would suggest writing a small C program to act as the shell, which runs and displays the output from your bash script.  The C program should ignore its arguments and reset its environment to a safe default, and then fork/exec() your bash script with a STDIN of /dev/null.  This way the user has absolutely no way to interact with the script.  I can provide an example if you need.